# My javascript jquery won't work?

Tags: theme-development, jquery

I am trying to make a mobile navigation for my site. However the jquery code won't work.
You can see what I am trying to do here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjdefrq9/).

I have the html in my header.php after body tag, css in my style.css

For javascript I enqueued it in my functions php:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/testJS.js', array('jquery'), true );
```

In my testJS.js I have this code:

```
( function( $ ) {
    $(".mobileButton").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle");
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

But when I click on the button nothing happens unlike my jsfiddle.
Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your enqueued JS file appearing in the source code for your website?

Comment: Yes it is but after I just checked, it seems to be on the top in the head tag for some reason. I think this might be the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't matter too much - as long as it's included after the jquery script is - are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No there are no errors..

Comment: Are there any console errors after you have clicked on your navigation icon?

Comment: Try the JS here: https://jsfiddle.net/9rap7o8n/ On page load your console should show the "Script loaded" message and when you click on the icon, it should show the other message - let me know if you see both messages

Comment: It says script loaded, but when I click on it nothing happens. Won't display the other message either. I tried adding it to the footer and it works also displays those messages. Maybe it's a javascript or wordpress thing...

Comment: When you added it to the footer did it display the "clicked" message after you clicked the button or not?

Comment: Yes it will display "Navigation clicked" every time I click the button but if I load the script in the header it will say "Script Loaded" and nothing will happen if I click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading your script in the footer:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/testJS.js', array('jquery'), false, true );`
```

The `true` parameter on the end tells WordPress to load this script in the footer instead of the header.

For more information, visit the Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/